# No source tracking support for type: NavigationMenu Winter'20

Tags: community, salesforcedx, winter20

According to the documentation, NavigationMenu should be supported int API v47 both in source tracing and unlocked packaged, but after trying to pull changes in navigation menu I am getting the following error:

$ sfdx force:source:pull --apiversion=47.0
No source tracking support for type: NavigationMenu. For details, visit https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage and select your API version. Skipping...

Scratch org is in winter 20 in project json  I have "sourceApiVersion": "47.0" and I have updated sfdx cls. Do you have any idea why it is not working?

Comment: You can also try to ask your question in this group: https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93A000000HTp1